# Change all the date's in my document, I know how to change 1 date correctly

Tags: sectioning

My date's are in a section. With help from Nicola: `\section*{\DTMdate{2014-06-17}}`, with `\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2})`, I can change 1 date at a time. It works for every section I write this code. But is there a way I can get it done for all the sections, (every section starts with a date and there are a lot sections. I would like to use a code? To change them all `\section*{\DTMdate{2014-06-17}}` works for one. But the date in the next section is different. So I could copy this for every section en change the date, but that is a lot of work. Is there a simple way?

Comment: Does your text editor allow regular expressions in its search and replace function? That would be the simplest method.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. In this case it would probably clear up any confusion as I am not sure exactly waht you want to do.  Do you just want to replace `2014-06-17` with some other specific date?  Do you want to replace them with today's date?

Comment: One option would be to use `\let\OldDTMdate\DTMdate \renewcommand{\DTMdate}{...\OldDTMdate}` to add the functionality that you desire, so would be helpful to know the details.

Comment: @PeterGrill I think karin may be looking for a quick way of converting `\section*{2014-06-17}` to `\section*{\DTMdate{2014-06-17}}`. Another possibility might be to redefine starred sections to parse the argument.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Oh, in that case redefining `\section*` is an option., but that would require more information such as does the OP have cases where the `\section*` contains something other than a date.

Comment: I would like to send you a screenshot, that will make it easier to show the problem, is this possible?

Comment: \sectio\part{title}n*{\DTMdate{17-6-14}}
\textbf{Karin Minnigh}: Adres paraplu, van Bijnkershoeklaan 10\\*
\section*{07-07-14}
\textbf{Peter Luijkx}: Hallo Karin, ik zat mij al af te vragen of jullie nog op vakantie waren of misschien net terug. Gr Peter\\* \section*{15-08-14}
\textbf{Karin Minnigh}: Ha Peter, we gaan morgen naar Vianen\\*  Here you see a short piece of the document,  every section starts with a new date. Only in the first line the date outcome looks good. I would like to change this all at once.  I thinks it is redefining  \section*.  But how?

Comment: @ Nicola, yes I can do the search and replace function. I tried that, but I do not know how I can do the code part for the changing date's. Is there a way, putting <> these or [] around the date? So it changes only the appearance of the date, not date it self?

Comment: @karin: Next time please edit the question and include the full code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use the editor's search/replace function to change all occurrences of `\section*` to `\MySection`, with which

1. it should be an easy search/replace operation
2. you don't loose the option to use the `section` without the date.

Below are MWEs for both the `yyyy-mm-dd` and `dd-mm-yy` date formats, which produce the following output:

[image]

### Code: `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\newcommand*{\MySection}[1]{\section*{\DTMdate{#1}}}

\begin{document}
  \MySection{2014-08-14} 
    some text
  \MySection{2014-09-22} 
    some text
\end{document}
```

### Code: `dd-mm-yy`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\def\parsesection#1#2-#3#4-#5#6{\section*{\DTMdate{20#5#6-#3#4-#1#2}}} 
\newcommand*{\MySection}[1]{\parsesection#1}

\begin{document}
  \MySection{14-08-14} 
    some text
  \MySection{22-09-14} 
    some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: The argument of `\DTMdate` needs to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD (so `2014-08-15` and `2014-09-22`), so perhaps an inner command is needed for `\MySection` to convert the format.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Opps, have corrected the date format.

Comment: From the OP's comments, I think maybe your original code actually replicated the format in the OP's document. In that case, it would need something like `\def\parsesection#1-#2-#3\relax{\section*{\DTMdate{20#3-#2-#1}}}` with `\newcommand*{\MySection}[1]{\parsesection#1\relax}`. (Assuming all dates are in the 21st century.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Yeah, the comments and the text in the question do not match. The answer here matches the code give in the question so think I should wait to hear back from the OP before addressing the change in format.

Comment: @Nicola and Peter, I am a beginner, so make lots of mistakes. I can see that changing\Section in \MySection works. Only my dutch way of writing the date is different than the English dat. We write it in 17-06-14, meaning 17 june 2014. So maybe I need to change something in the DTMdate. When this is fixed I can do it. And I also need to learn how to change in this text the code in light grey. working on this

Comment: @karin: Ok, have provided another solution that works with the `dd-mm-yy` format.

Comment: @Peter, you made my day beautiful. It works

Comment: @Nicola and Peter, it is working beautiful.